# C# Visual Studio Windows Forms Move Object With Mouse Click

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My forms consists of 4 labels that i would like to be click and dropped at a location. I need to be able to set the movObj as a type e.g. Label1 = movOject. Im asking this question to write each label name to the movObj. I know i can just put this whole code in each label click event but i like my code to be as short as possible. Ill handle the drop event once i figured this out so this question is not about that. Just setting movObj to the label clicked. Then it can moved to its possition. Help appreciated.

```
private Point firstPoint = new Point();
    public void INIT()
    {
        movObj.MouseDown += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) { firstPoint = Control.MousePosition; }
        };

        movObj.MouseMove += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                //creates temp point
                Point temp = Control.MousePosition;
                Point res = new Point(firstPoint.X - temp.X, firstPoint.Y - temp.Y);

                //apply value to object
                movObj.Location = new Point(movObj.Location.X - res.X, movObj.Location.Y - res.Y);

                //updates first point
                firstPoint = temp;
            }
        };
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the events is something like:

```
event(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In your code, `ss` is the `sender` and `ee` is the `e`.

It seems you know how to use `EventArgs` because you're using `ee` in your code. Now, the `sender` is the object that caused the event. In your case it is the label that was clicked. You can simply cast it from `object` to `Label` like this:

```
Label myLabel = (Label)sender;
```

and then you can get its text using `myLabel.Text`.

Comment: This code is pretty advnaced for me it is the first time i have ever needed to do what i am trying to accomplish. I tried setting the paremneter like you said but it is not working. Does it have something to do with movObj as this is set to one of my label names on a Windows Form? Can i just not save this as a type variable within my code then write to my label selection for it to fire up?. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Edit your question and add the code where you assign values to `movObj` and what you exactly want to do. Because if you're saying that `movObj` is *set to one of my label names*, what does "label name" mean? If you mean the label control itself, then you don't even need the code that I provided. Yes you can save it as a type variable, but I don't understand what you mean by *then write to my label selection for it to fire up*.